# How can i make an google chrome extension open a incognito

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, incognito-mode

I want to make an extension that opens an incognito mode when you click on a button.

I want to make this extension for chrome but i also like to do it for firefox, but first the chrome extension

this is the only feature.

I hope to have an explantion for this and know if it is posssible

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create

Answer (score 0):

You can open in `incognito` by setting it to `true` in [chrome.windows](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows)

For example:

```
chrome.windows.create({incognito: true, url});
```